# update existing index keypath of an object store on indexed db upgrade

Tags: indexeddb

I am using Indexed DB for offline storage. The DB has many Object Store and every Object Store has indexes. IDB Index consist name and keyPath(col on which we apply indexing) property. Usually we keep both properties value same(to easily identify the index by the col name). Now my requirement is **for an index only change the KeyPath(the name of index remains the same)**.

In the upgradeneeded callback(DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded) I am able to get the object store from the transaction.

```
DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        var transaction = event.target.transaction;
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("objectStore Name");
        var IDBIndexObj = objectStore.index("indexName");//exception
        if(IDBIndexObj.keyPath !== "newKeyPath"){ 
            //delete index and create new index with the new keypath
        }

    };
```

**But the object store only have the names of the indexes. When I tries to create IDBIndex object an exception is thrown as the transaction is of "versionchange" type**. 
So, how can I get the existing index keypath to compare with the new keypath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
function onUpgradeNeeded(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  var storeNames = db.objectStoreNames;
  var myStore = null;

  if(storeNames.contains('myStoreName')) {
    myStore = event.target.transaction.objectStore('myStoreName');
  } else {
    myStore = db.createObjectStore('myStoreName', ...);
  }

  var indexNames = myStore.indexNames;
  var desiredKeyPathForMyIndex = ...;

  if(indexNames.contains('myIndexName')) {
    var myIndex = myStore.index('myIndexName');
    var currentKeyPath = myIndex.keyPath;
    if(currentKeyPath != desiredKeyPathForMyIndex) {
      myStore.deleteIndex('myIndexName');
      myStore.createIndex('myIndexName', desiredKeyPathForMyIndex);
    }
  } else {
    myStore.createIndex('myIndexName', desiredKeyPathForMyIndex);
  }
}
```

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBIndex to learn more about accessing the other properties of IDBIndex.